# BigQuery Error – UNIQUE_HEAP requires an int32 argument

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

Using legacy SQL, I am trying to use `COUNT(DISTINCT field, n)` in Google BigQuery. But I am get following error:

> UNIQUE_HEAP requires an int32 argument which is greater than 0 (error code: invalidQuery)

Here is my query that I have used:

```
SELECT
    hits.page.pagePath AS Page,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, INTEGER(visitId)), 1e6) AS UniquePageviews,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId, 1e6) as Users
FROM
    [xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20170101]
GROUP BY
    Page
ORDER BY
    UniquePageviews DESC
LIMIT
    20
```

BigQuery is not even showing line number of error therefore I am not sure which line is causing this error.

> What could be possible cause of above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `1e6` in your `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. Instead, use an actual INTEGER value for the 2nd parameter `'N'` (default is 1000), or use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT()` instead.

[COUNT(DISTINCT) documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct)

[EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT() documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct)

> If you require greater accuracy from COUNT(DISTINCT), you can specify
>   a second parameter, n, which gives the threshold below which exact
>   results are guaranteed. By default, n is 1000, but if you give a
>   larger n, you will get exact results for COUNT(DISTINCT) up to that
>   value of n. However, giving larger values of n will reduce scalability
>   of this operator and may substantially increase query execution time
>   or cause the query to fail.
>
> To compute the exact number of distinct values, use
>   EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT. Or, for a more scalable approach, consider using
>   GROUP EACH BY on the relevant field(s) and then applying COUNT(*). The
>   GROUP EACH BY approach is more scalable but might incur a slight
>   up-front performance penalty.